# Replacing a string using sed command

Tags: sed

How to use sed command to match strings starting with &# in my html file and replace it with space ?

- Example: `&#192`
- Result: space
- Should be completely replaced by space

It should work for all the HTML codes with three or 4 digits trailing `&#`.

Basically HTML codes: http://webdesign.about.com/library/bl_htmlcodes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yep got it `sed -e 's_&#[0-9]*_ _g'`

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed 's/\&#[0-9]*/ /g' your
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the &# like this

```
abc="&#192"
echo $abc | sed 's/\&\#/ /g'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> echo "&#192" | sed -e 's_&#_ _g'
 192
```

in perl:

```
> echo "&#192" | perl -pe 's/&#/ /g'
 192
```

in awk :

```
> echo "&#192" | awk '{gsub(/&#/," ");print}'
 192
```

Comment: I don't want 192 as result,it should also be replaced with space too