# Find and replace a substring in shell script

Tags: string, bash, shell

I have a file which contains some strings for example in file `my_file.txt`, I have strings

```
foo_eusa.r1
foo_chnc.r5
foo_deu.r10
.
.
.
```

Now I wanted to check for a substring whether it exists in the file and if it exists I wanted to modify the entire string or if it does not I will add it.

For example I have a new string `foo_eusa.r4` I wanted to search for all occurences of substring `foo_eusa` in the file. If it exists (in the above it exists `foo_eusa.r1`) then replace **r1** with **r4** so the string becomes `foo_eusa.r4` instead of `foo_eusa.r1` in all occurences. If `foo_eusa` does not exist then the new string `foo_eusa.r4` is to be added

I treid checking using grep -q but it gives only the first match and also could not find a way to replace the sub strings

Comment: What have you tried? Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: Use `grep` to decide what you need to do (add or sed).

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing a string using sed command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12363338/608639), [Using 'sed' to find and replace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159367/56041), [How can I replace a string in a file(s)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112023/56041), [Replace substring with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14194702/608639), [sed to replace partial string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21146211/608639), etc.

Answer (score -1):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -i~ -pe 's/^foo_eusa\..*/foo_eusa.r4/ and $changed = 1;
              END { print "foo_eusa.r4\n" unless $changed }' -- file
```

If you need to process more than one file, it's a bit more complex:

```
perl  -i~ -ne '
    s/^foo_eusa\..*/foo_eusa.r4/ and $changed = 1;
    print;
    if (eof) {
        print "foo_eusa.r4\n" unless $changed;
        $changed = 0;
    }' -- file*
```

- `-i~` modifies the file "in place", leaving a backup with the `~` extension
- `-p` reads the input line by line and outputs each line after processing
- `-n` is like `-p`, but it doesn't output the line unless told to `print`
- `$changed` is used as a flag. When the substitution is triggered, it's set to 1. If it's not 1 at the END (i.e. when the processing is finished), the string is added to the output. In case of several files, the flag must be handled for each file, so [eof](http://p3rl.org/eof) is used to indicate the end of file.